# Unit test Abstract class method that calls concrete child method

Tags: php, unit-testing, phpunit

I have an abstract class that has an abstract method and a concrete method.

The concrete method calls the abstract method and uses its return value.

How can this return value be mocked?

So the abstract class is

```
abstract class MyAbstractClass
{
    /**
     * @return array()
     */
    abstract function tester();

    /**
     * @return array()
     */
    public function myconcrete()
    {
        $value = $this->tester();  //Should be an array

        return array_merge($value, array("a","b","c");
    }
}
```

I want to test the myconcrete method, so i want to mock the return value to tester - but it is called inside the method?

Is this possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes it is possible. Your test should look like this:

```
class MyTest extends PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase
{    
    public function testTester() {
        // mock only the method tester all other methods will keep unchanged
        $stub = $this->getMockBuilder('MyAbstractClass')
            ->setMethods(array('tester'))
            ->getMock();

        // configure the stub so that tester() will return an array
        $stub->expects($this->any())
            ->method('tester')
            ->will($this->returnValue(array('1', '2', '3')));

        // test myconcrete()
        $result = $stub->myconcrete();    

        // assert result is the correct array
        $this->assertEquals($result, array(
            '1', '2', '3', 'a', 'b', 'c' 
        )); 
    }
}
```

Note that I'm using PHPUnit 3.7.10